# What is causing default membership type error?

Tags: civimember, default-settings

On contribution page, I set "Membership One" as default membership, but then "Membership Two" is what shows up as default membership choice for public. I tried changing the default to other membership type, and it never "sets" as the correct membership I want defaulted but rather chooses another membership. It's like the membership type that is visible to public, is actually programmed as something else in Civicrm. Using WP.

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm if you can replicate this on the demo site please

Comment: How do I do that?^^^

Comment: link for testing in demo https://civicrm.org/sandboxes - username and password is demo

Comment: I couldn't put in my civi info in demo site, doesn't seem like there is a way to just drop my civicrm component in there if that's what I am supposed to do to test it.

Comment: You would replicate by creating a Contribution page with memberships and confirming it works / fails in same way it does on your install

Comment: Ok, I tried it out and seems to work on demo but not sure why it wouldn't work on demo. So, error doesn't replicate but not sure why it would or else everyone would be having this same problem and seems to be only me.

Comment: Any ideas for me? Why would default membership type on back-end not translate to default membership type on front-end? If I change default to another membership type it changes again to a different membership type on back end.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this was that there was a bug whereby the 'weight' was being used in one situation, whereas the type ID was being used in the other. And this error only showed up if you had changed the 'weight' ie the order of your Membership Types.

To quote the ticket in [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19871)

> In the contribution page edit form, the default is selected by membership_type_id. When the contribution form is displayed, it's using the weight of the membership type instead

This has now been fixed by the Fuzion Team.